# Powers of odd primes as a divisor

Tags: number-theory

Working on some number theory and i have to show that for an odd prime, p, with exponent $r \geq 1$ that $p^r | (x-1)(x+1) \Rightarrow p^r | (x-1)$ or $p^r | (x+1)$
and deduce that $ x \equiv \pm 1$ (mod $2^r$) are the only solutions to $ x \equiv 1$ (mod $2^r$)

Since $p$ is prime I know that if $p = (y+1)(y-1)$ then $p | (y-1)$ or $p|(y+1)$ (or both). I then then try to extend this to $p^r$ by setting $(y+1)^r = (x+1)$ and $(y-1)^r = (x-1)$ by im having trouble presenting my argument in a coherent way to show that $p^r | (x+1)$ or $p^r |(x-1)$.

Comment: $p$ in general cannot equal $(y+1)(y-1)$ for some $y \in \Bbb{N}$ because primes cannot be factored... The only way that can be true is the one case of $p=3$ and $y=2$. You get the reduntant equality $3 =3\cdot 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p^r$ divides $(x+1)(x-1)$ then the factorization of $(x+1)(x-1)$ has the factor $p$ repeated $r$ times. Since $p$ cannot divide simultaneously $x+1$ and $x-1$, then the $r$ times that $p$ appears come from the same factor, that is, $p^r$ divides $x+1$ or $p^r$ divides $x-1$.

Comment: This doesn't work for $p =2.$

Comment: The question states that p must be an odd prime

Answer (score 0):

If $p^s|(x-1),p^t|(x+1)$ where $s>t\ge0$

$x-1=p^s(S),x+1=p^t(T)\implies x+1-(x-1)=p^{s-t}(Sp^t-T)\implies p^{s-t}|2$

If $s-t\ge1, p=2,s-t=1$